# How to find an element using Watir by inline css styles

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, watir

How can I find an element using it's inline style declaration?

Here's my attempt:

```
results = browser.div(:id => 'summon_panel')
                 .div(:class => 'tabs2_container')
                 .div(:class => 'pane_inner', :index => 4)
                 .div(:class => 'pagination_tabs_container')
                 .div(:style => 'display: block') # This is what I've added.
                 .divs(:class => 'rank')
```

And result:

> Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException (unable to locate element, using {:style=>"display: block", :tag_name=>"div"}):
>     app/controllers/streams_controller.rb:61:in `saveranks'

Comment: Is `"display: block"` the _exact_ inline style on the element?

Comment: @MattBall: Had to add that final semi-colon. `;` - Thanks for the heads up! Write as answer and I'll mark it for you.

Comment: It usually helps if you share relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Copypasta at OP's request:</sup>

Is `"display: block"` the *exact* inline style on the element?